# can i use getElementByID('oct_6_2013') when it comes to a DOMDocument->saveHTML or does it have to be a DOMDocument->loadHTML

Tags: php

all of the code i seen that refers to PHP getElementByID all refers to load and not save...

Should i just use Javascript?

Code is very long but here's a snippet.

```
$row3->appendChild($cel7_3 = $cc->createElement('td', $row3_cel2 = (isSeT($cel7_3val1))? $cel7_3val1 : '&nbsp;'));
            $cel7_3->setAttribute('id', $fMonth.'_'.$fDate++.'_'.$fYear);
            $cel7_3->setAttribute('class', 'Sapro925583');
            $cel7_3->setAttribute('style', 'width: 51pt;');
            $cel7_3->setAttribute('height', '20');
```

It creates a calendar and on a particular date I want to change the Class.
But not working.

Comment: I don't think anyone understands your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html which is being generated?

Try log the id of the generated element and compare with the id getElementByID